# Creating an entangled state in Hadamard basis (Qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, entanglement, hadamard

I am familiar with  building a quantum circuit of an entangled pair providing that they are in the computational basis:

|ψ⟩ = 1/√2 (|00⟩ + |11⟩)

[image]

This  circuit works great.

I am trying to build the same circuit but on the Hadamard basis (+, -):
|ψ⟩ = 1/√2 (|++⟩ + |--⟩)

I have tried this circuit but it didn't work. Instead of finding (00, 11), I am getting (00, 10).

[image]

Please let me know how to build such circuit.
Can I  choose in which basis the measurement should be done , like the results be (++ , --)?

Best,

Answer (score 2):

The $H\otimes H$ should come after the X and CNOT

$$H_1|00\rangle=|+0\rangle$$
$$CNOT|+0\rangle=|00\rangle+|11\rangle$$
$$HH(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)=|++\rangle+|--\rangle$$

The equivalence of X base and Z base up to Hadamard, tells us that you can take a circuit that works well and known in Z basis, operate with it in the Z basis, and than just change the base

What you tryed to do, is transform into X basis, and than to try to act with a circuit that works in a known manner on the Z basis, but you acted with it in the wrong basis (X).

Comment: Thank you, this is so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result in $|+>$ , $|->$ basis you have to perform the measurement in X basis because $|+>$ and $|->$ are the eigenvectos of PauliX gate. One way to do that  is to apply Hadamard gate on all the qubits of the QuantumCircuit and then perform measurement.
So applying $H \otimes H$ on $1/\sqrt(2)(|++>+|-->)$ will produce $1/\sqrt(2)(|00>+|11>)$. Now if you perform measurement you will get $|00>$ and $|11>$ with equal probability. Considering the application of Hadamard gate within the measurement process you can now say $|00>$ and $|11>$ corresponds to the state $|++>$ and $|-->$ respectively.
Here is the qiskit implementation of what I just said[image]
And the resulting histogram looks like[image]
For more elaborate discussion you may look [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/single-qubit-gates.html#:%7E:text=To%20measure%20it%20in%20X,%E2%88%92%20b%202%20%7C%20%E2%88%92%20%E2%9F%A9%20).

Comment: Thank you, this is so helpful.